# Disable 2FA on Microsoft 365

Tags: imap

My organisation uses Microsoft365 for Outlook email.

Microsoft disabled basic authentication on October 2022, although there was an extension given to some organisations, including ours, to 25th January 2023.

Is my organisation able to switch off 2FA on my account for IMAP access, or is this not possible? App passwords have been turned off when Microsoft deprecated basic auth.

I'm having a hard time finding a definite answer on the Internet.

Comment: **Do you guys know if my organisation is able to switch off 2FA on my account for IMAP access, or is this not possible?** - Those two things are unrelated to each other. Being MFA enabled or disabled has no bearing on legacy auth protocols like IMAP and POP being blocked.

Comment: You're co mingling two separate but related topics. Microsoft announced **many years ago** that support for legacy protocols and authentication would end. One side effect is that older applications with older authentication methods were impacted. Instead of the semi disjointed regurgitating of this, just tell us what you are doing that isn't working. The client application you are using, the network port numbers, secure or insecure, oauth, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Someone please turn this into a comment because 50 reputation is required.

@joeqwerty Which two things? Your bold sentence, which is my question as was originally posed, is not ambiguous. Perhaps some comprehension problems here; in fact in your sentence which comes right after, you refer to IMAP / POP being blocked, which is not the issue here and was never mentioned in my question. Perhaps you're confusing the meaning of basic authentication with IMAP/POP?

@Greg Askew: The first three sentences are irrelevant to answering my question; the fourth shows that you didn't read my question properly (overworked?), and the last is asking for, once again, irrelevant details: client application is irrelevant because my question is about a protocol, network port number has nothing to do with the authentication I'm talking about, secure or insecure who knows what you mean (TLS etc? unclear...)

The question is clear, let's try once again in a simplified form this time: IMAP access to Outlook in Office365 is now conditional to 2FA, is it possible to disable this requirement and use user and password (over StartTLS, say)